# Proof of the existence of a function in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this one math problem where I just don't know how to work this out:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function with the properties $f(0,0)=0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. Show that a function $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the property $$f(x,y)=g(x,y)\cdot(x+y)\qquad\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$$ exists.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me out.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x,y)=g(x+y)(x+y)$?

Comment: No, I mean $f(x,y)=g(x,y)\cdot(x+y)$.

Comment: Try and use Taylor expansion

Comment: Compute the directional derivative alongside the $x + y = 0$ line.

Comment: Or just solve $f_x-f_y=0$

Answer (score 2):

Well, the only problem might be if $x+y=0$ and $f\left(x,y\right)\ne0$, in which case there cannot be such $g$. Had we known that $f\left(x,y\right)=0$ whenever $x+y=0$, we could have defined
$$g\left(x,y\right)=\left\{\begin{matrix}\frac{f\left(x,y\right)}{x+y},&x+y\neq 0\\0,&x+y=0\end{matrix}\right.$$

Let us consider the function $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $h\left(t\right)=f\left(t,-t\right)$. As we said, it suffices to show that $h=0$. Differentiating $h$, using the chain rule, we get
$$\frac{dh}{dt}\left(t\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$
here $\frac{dx}{dt}=1$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=-1$ (since $x=t$ and $y=-t$, so $\frac{dh}{dt}=0$, meaning $h$ is constant. Since $h\left(0\right)=f\left(0,0\right)=0$, $h=0$, as required.

Comment: .. and if we set $g(t,-t) = \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y)=(t,-t)}$ instead of $0$ then we can even get $g$ to be continuous (though that was not required by the problem).

Comment: Why would $g$ be continuous if we used this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work with the Taylor formula for higher dimensions: $f(x,y)= f(0,0)+ gradf(0,0)(x,y) +r(x,y)$ and $r$ is a sublinear function. This would lead to something like  $ f(x,y)= \frac{df}{dx}(x+y) +r(x,y)$ . You still have to put some work in how to deal with $r$. Are there any properties that $g(x)$ should have according to your task?